# Selecting Grouped Items in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

This worked in EF 6.4:

```
from a in Addresses
group a by new {a.StreetName, a.StreetNumber} into agrp
where agrp.Count() > 3
from aitem in agrp
select aitem
```

If EF Core 5 I get:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'agrp => agrp' could
> not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

Why? Is there a different way to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var addressGroupQuery = from a in Addresses
                        group a by new {a.StreetName, a.StreetType} into agrp
                        where agrp.Count() > 3
                        select agrp.Max(a => a.AddressID);
                
var addresses = from a in Addresses
                where addressGroupQuery.Contains(a.AddressID)
                select a;
```

Note the addressGroupQuery remains a deferred query (no ToList). Generates some clean looking SQL too:

```
SELECT [a].[AddressID], [a].[City], [a].[Country], [a].[StreetName], [a].[StreetNumber], [a].[StreetType], [a].[UnitNumber]
FROM [Address] AS [a]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Address] AS [a0]
    GROUP BY [a0].[StreetName], [a0].[StreetType]
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 3) AND (MAX([a0].[AddressID]) = [a].[AddressID]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with the data being loaded into memory, a simple solution could be to add `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` after `Addresses`:

```cs
from a in Addresses.ToList() // or .AsEnumerable()
group a by new {a.StreetName, a.StreetNumber} into agrp
where agrp.Count() > 3
from aitem in agrp
select aitem
```

Note that this (in SqlServer) translates into:

```sql
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[StreetName], [a].[StreetNumber]
FROM [Addresses] AS [a]
```

In EF Core, `GroupBy` is (in many cases) not translated to SQL, but is run in memory.
(To avoid accidentally loading a lot of data into memory, EF will throw an exception unless `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` is called to indicate that this is intentional.)

> (...) Since no database structure can represent an `IGrouping`, `GroupBy` operators have no translation in most cases. When an aggregate operator is applied to each group, which returns a scalar, it can be translated to SQL `GROUP BY` in relational databases. (...)

- [Complex query operators, GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby)

The article also has an example of a query which translates into `group by` with a filter on `Count` (included below).
The example doesn't fully cover the example in the question, unfortunately. It would not return the relevant Address-objects, only the group-by Key and Count.

```cs
var query = from p in context.Set<Post>()
            group p by p.AuthorId into g
            where g.Count() > 0
            orderby g.Key
            select new
            {
                g.Key,
                Count = g.Count()
            };
```

```sql
SELECT [p].[AuthorId] AS [Key], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [Posts] AS [p]
GROUP BY [p].[AuthorId]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY [p].[AuthorId]
```